# php mysql array merge

Tags: mysql, arrays

Retrieving data on my site often involves looking in multiple tables. I'm trying to merge (retrieve) the data from several different tables.  This code works great for retrieving "Favorite Members" but does not work for retrieving "Favorite Groups".  I am perplexed.
I think I need to make a nested array but I don't know how I'm just a beginner.

```
$favgroups = array();
$favsql = "SELECT * FROM group_favorites WHERE user_id = $member_id";
$query = @mysql_query($favsql);

$favgroups_total = @mysql_num_rows($query);

while ($favgroups_result1 = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$group_id = $favgroups_result1['group_id'];

// get details from other tables
$favgrpsql2 = "SELECT * FROM group_profile WHERE group_id = $group_id";
$query2 = @mysql_query($favgrpsql2);
$favgroups_result2 = @mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$groupname = $favgroups_result2['group_name'];

$favgrpsql3 = "SELECT * FROM group_profile WHERE group_id = $group_id";
$query3 = @mysql_query($favgrpsql3);
$favgroups_result3 = @mysql_fetch_array($query3);
$adminid = $favgroups_result3['admin_id'];

$favgrpsql4 = "SELECT * FROM member_profile WHERE user_id = $adminid";
$query4 = @mysql_query($favgrpsql4);
$favgroups_result4 = @mysql_fetch_array($query4);
$adminname = $favgroups_result4['user_name'];

$favgrpsql5 = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE user_id = $adminid";
$query5 = @mysql_query($favgrpsql5);
$favgroups_result5 = @mysql_fetch_array($query5);
$photo = $favgroups_result5['file_name'];


$favgroups_result1 = array('favgroup_id' => $group_id);
$favgroups_result2 = array('favgroup_name' => $groupname);
$favgroups_result3 = array('favadmin_id' => $adminid);
$favgroups_result4 = array('favadmin_name' => $adminname);
$favgroups_result5 = array('favadmin_photo' => $photo);

$fgroup_merged = @array_merge($favgroups_result1, $favgroups_result2,
$favgroups_result3, $favgroups_result4, $favgroups_result5);

$favgroups[] = $fgroup_merged;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post sql dumps of your tables with (SOME) of the data in each. It might be possible to do what you want purely in MySql

Comment: In addition you are using mysql_query functions, they are deprecated. Please use mysqli functions instead. See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php and http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

Comment: `$favgrpsql2` and `$favgrpsql3` look exactly the same. Why don't you get `group_name` and `admin_id` at once?

Comment: I don't have a good understanding of sql dumps  =/    group_name and admin_id are in the same table but when I try to pull them at the same time, I only get one result or the other.  Are there any visible errors in this code?  It works elsewhere but not here.  I'm baffled.